# Using Arcade, AGOL, and Attribute Expressions to Create a Text field with Quotes

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-online, arcade

I am working on creating a Attribute Expression that would display HTML with quotes in the field. I tried putting double quotes for the inner quotes, but I keep getting "Parse Error: Unexpected String". Here is how I am writing out the expression which I know works with Python.

```
"<a href=tel:""PHONE NUMBER"">PHONE NUMBER</a>"
```

What it should produce:

```
<a href=tel:"PHONE NUMBER">PHONE NUMBER</a>
```

Does anyone know how to print out quotes within a text field using Attribute Expression?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using single quotes for the entire string with double quotes in the middle:

```
'<a href="sample text">sample text</a>'
```

Comment: Yes this works!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the "TextFormatting.DoubleQuote" function in arcade in order to accomplish this.

```
var PhoneNumber = "915555555555"

"<a href=tel:" + TextFormatting.DoubleQuote + PhoneNumber + TextFormatting.DoubleQuote + ">" + PhoneNumber + "</a>"
```

Source: https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/constants/